# Calling python script from commandline gives syntax error when class doesn't inherit anything, why is that?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, command-line

This question has (for me) no real implication. I just found this out by coincidence and I am curious about the mechanics behind it. I got the folling example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
just an example
"""

class exampleClass():
    'this is just an example'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)
```

Running this in eclipse print "just an example". However, when I try to run this in the terminal I get the following error:

```
File "./temp.py", line 6
   class exampleClass():
                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now, when I change the class in the example script to inherit from dict

```
class exampleClass(dict):
```

and run it from the commandline it also prints "just an example".
So why do classes have to inherit something to work from commandline, but not from eclipse?

Comment: I tried this code with all Python version from 2.5 up to the current trunk (excluding 3.0), and it works fine.  Are you sure your file looks exactly as in the post?

Comment: Yes, I copied it directly from the file. I run it using ./temp.py, but python temp.py gives the same result

Comment: Appareantly lower than 2.5 did give an error, and as Sven Marnach said 2.5 and up doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Python 2.7.2 grammar](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html), the following syntax is incorrect:

```
class exampleClass():
    'this is just an example'
```

It should be either

```
class exampleClass:
    'this is just an example'
```

or

```
class exampleClass(object): # or `dict' etc
    'this is just an example'
```

In all probability you're using two different versions of the Python interpreter, and for some reason one of the interpreters is allowing the invalid syntax and the other isn't.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: OK, that explains it.  The oldest version I tested with was 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the parenthesis

```
class exampleClass:
    pass
```

unless you want to inherit from another class, e.g.:

```
class exampleClass(object):
    pass
```

Comment: Incase anyone gets this syntax error, this does solve the problem.